# Copying index file from S3 bucket into apache using cloudformation userdata not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am quite new to cloudformation and AWS. However, I have tried to run a cloudformation script to create a role and copy S3 bucket file into an apache server.
THis is the script:

```
SRS3ReadOnlyEC2:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: WebServersS3ReadRole
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - S3:List*
                  - S3:Get*
                Resource: "*"
  
  ProfileWithRolesForOurApp:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties: 
      Roles:
        - !Ref SRS3ReadOnlyEC2
 WebAppLaunchConfig:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          apt-get update -y
          apt-get install unzip awscli -y
          apt-get install apache2 -y
          systemctl start apache2.service
          cd /var/www/html
          aws s3 cp s3://my-mini-site/index.html .
      ImageId: ami-0729e439b6769d6ab
      KeyName: keyname
      SecurityGroups:
      - Ref: WebServerSecGroup
      InstanceType: t3.medium
      BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: "/dev/sdk"
        Ebs:
          VolumeSize: '10'
```

The problem is that the apache server starts ok and displays the apache server default page. This means that the S3 file I copied either did not copy or something else has gone wrong.
The S3 bucket is public, so I am really struggling to understand what I am doing wrong.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

ETA: From my log file, everything works great untili start getting this:

```
   Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started The Apache HTTP Server.
[   67.919309] cloud-init[1908]: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.6) ...
[   67.934647] cloud-init[1908]: Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.53) ...
[   68.086923] cloud-init[1908]: Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
[   68.438494] cloud-init[1908]: Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
[   68.527745] cloud-init[1908]: Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
[   70.280139] cloud-init[1908]: fatal error: Unable to locate credentials
[   70.745576] cloud-init[1908]: fatal error: Unable to locate credentials
```

Which of the credentials are we talking about here please? Is it the AWS configured profile? Thanks again

Comment: If you can SSH or SSM into EC2 instance, check the cloud-init logs
`/var/log/cloud-init.log`
`/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

You can do it from console as well 
 - Monitor and Troubleshoot > Get System Log

Comment: Your userdata script is run as root. If you need HTML assets to be owned by another user (apache?) then you need to run the `aws s3 cp` as that user (or subsequently `chown` the files).

Comment: @Mahesh Thanks! I have accessed the log file and found that everything falls apart after apache starts because it cannot locate credentials. pardon my naivety but do you know what credential exactly and how I am supposed to make it find it. Thanks

Comment: There could be many reasons. However in this case, 
1. I'm suspecting IAM instance profile is not associated with the role. Please verify if the Instance profile is associated with the role from console. 
2. I am assuming the Ec2 instance is created from Amazon provided AMI. if not make sure that latest version of  aws cli is installed.

Comment: @Mahesh 1. Yes the IAM instance created in the script is associated with the created role. 2. Ec2 Instance in this case is created from Amazon provided AMI.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks a lot for coming to my aid. I don't understand. Do you mean I do something like sudo aws s3 cp? Pardon me, again I am a novice in all this. I have just managed to successfully write a script that worked and i am stuck at this point.

Comment: @Mahesh 1. YES!!!! that was where i missed it. I did not associate the Instance with the role in my script. I was missin this: IamInstanceProfile: !Ref ProfileWithRolesForOurApp

Thanks Again!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thanks to @Mahesh, I found out that I did not associate the created role with the Instance. In the WebLaunchConfig resource, I had omitted this property:

```
IamInstanceProfile: !Ref ProfileWithRolesForOurApp
```

After including that line of code, the stack worked like a charm!